# The difference between tool and means

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I've done the research regarding the definition of those words that I took from a dictionary.

> **Means**
>
> an action, an object or a system by which a result is achieved; a way
> of achieving or doing something

> E.g.
>
> **means of something** Email is a highly effective **means** of communication.

> **Tool**
>
> a thing that helps you to do your job or to achieve something

> E.g.
>
> An email newsletter can be a very effective communication **tool**.

By the way, I took the examples from the dictionary I'm using (OALD) as well.

As you can see there, both are similar (to my perspective). Can you tell me the significant difference between these 2 words?

Comment: A tool is not just something that "helps you do your job".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**means** can often be replaced by **way**.

A **tool** was originally an implement used by a craftsman or a labourer: such as a hammer. It still has this meaning, and when an email newsletter is described as a tool, *tool* is a *metaphor*. We forget that  **most** words began as metaphors. A "way" was originally a path or road.

We **use** a tool, but it is not a *method*. You don't break glass by hammer but by means of a hammer. A hammer is neither a "*system by which a result is achieved*" nor "*a way of achieving or doing something*".

So when you see **tool** or **means** ask yourself, "Is it a road or a hammer?"!